# Flexible function for updating DB records from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is there any way to make the below-given code reusable for different tables, e.g. using `foreach`? So, how to send and use arrays of column names and values? Any example is highly appreciated.

```
<?php
    include_once 'include/DatabaseConnector.php';
    if(isset($_POST['flightNum'])) {
        $flightNum=$_POST['flightNum'];
        $from=$_POST['from'];
        $STADate=$_POST['STADate'];
        $query = 'UPDATE flightschedule 
                  SET frm="'.$from.'",STADate="'.$STADate.'"
                  WHERE flightNum="'.$flightNum.'"';
        DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQuery($query);
        echo '1';
    } else { 
        echo '0'; 
    }
?>
```

UPDATE: What if I don't know column names apriori? How to create flexible UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert your code into a reusable function. for example.

```
function updateDB($tableName, $flightNum, $from, $STADate) {
    include_once 'include/DatabaseConnector.php';
    $query = 'UPDATE ' . $tableName 
              SET frm="'.$from.'",STADate="'.$STADate.'"
              WHERE flightNum="'.$flightNum.'"';
    $execute = DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQuery($query);
    return $execute;
}
```

and to use it

```
if(isset($_POST['flightNum']) {
    $update = updateDB('flightschedule', $_POST['flightNum'], $_POST['from'], $_POST['STADate']);
    echo $update;
}
```

**Update:**

> I want to send an array of column names to the function 'updateDB'.
>   Let's say these are column names for SET and WHERE parts of UPDATE
>   statement. And then I could use FOREACH, but I need some example for
>   this.

this is how you can do it.

```
function updateDB($tableName, $columns, $where) {
    //do some validation here to check if proper data is being passed like
    if(!isarray($columns)) {
        throw new Exception('argument two $columns should be an associative array');
    }
    include_once 'include/DatabaseConnector.php';
    $query  = 'UPDATE ' . $tableName;
    foreach($columns as $column => $data) {
        $query .= ' SET ' . $column . ' = ' . $data . ', ';
    }
    //remove last comma from the update query string
    $query = substr($query, 0, -1);
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . $where['column'] . ' = ' . $where['value'];
    $execute = DatabaseConnector::ExecuteQuery($query);
    return $execute;
}
```

and to use it.

```
if(isset($_POST['flightNum']) {
    $columns = array(
        'frm' => $_POST['frm'],
        'STADate' => $_POST['STADate']
    );
    $where = array(
        'column'=> 'flightNum', 
         'value' =>  $_POST['flightNum']
    );
    $update = updateDB('flightschedule', $columns, $where);
    echo $update;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I don't know column names apriori? How to create flexible UPDATE statement?

Comment: how would you insert a record to DB if you don't know where to put it?

Comment: You have to pass the column name(s) in as well, and may be the types and the where clause, and that's just for simple queries. Don't do it, you don't get flexible code, you get fragile code. Write a function for each "function", anything else will just turn into a horrible mess and a technical debt you will never be able to pay.

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar: That's the case. I want to send an array of column names to the function 'updateDB'. Let's say these are column names for SET and WHERE parts of UPDATE statement. And then I could use FOREACH, but I need some example for this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function generateUpdateQuery($table, $fields, $where) {
    $updateFields = array();
    foreach ($fields as $k => $v) {
        $updateFields[] = $k.' = \''.$v.'\'';
    }
    $sqlQuery = 'UPDATE '.$table.
                ' SET '.implode(', ', $updateFields).
                ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);

    return $sqlQuery;
}

echo generateUpdateQuery('table_name',
                        array(
                            'field_a' => '10',
                            'field_b' => 'hello',
                            'field_c' => 'world'),
                        array(
                            'id=12',
                            'datetime > NOW()')
                        );
```

Keep in mind that this is a simple example without any security check. Something like PDO would be recommended.
Moreover, if you're looking for something more robust and flexible you should give a look to a ORM system, like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)